# Cannot convert type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' to

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to iterate all properties in one of my classes :

```
public MDInstrument() : base()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MDInstrument).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo item in properties)
        {
            var tick = item as TickData;
        }
    }
```

when I inspect the var properties I can see all the properties correctly

[image]

but on the line:

```
 var tick = item as TickData;
```

I am getting the error:

[image]

ADDITION

Hi Thanks for the feedback. I am not trying to get the value. The code is in the constructor. I am trying to loop the objects in the class and if they are of type 'TickData' then I want to add them to a list. I am doing this by attempting the cast using the as keyword. I must be missing something.

Comment: Better post error messages as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: please do accept answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx),  that will give the value and then you can convert that in your desired type.

```
 private static void GetPropertyValues(Object obj)
   {
      Type t = obj.GetType();
      Console.WriteLine("Type is: {0}", t.Name);
      PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
      Console.WriteLine("Properties (N = {0}):", 
                        props.Length);
      foreach (var prop in props)
         if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("   {0} ({1}): {2}", prop.Name,
                              prop.PropertyType.Name,
                              prop.GetValue(obj));
         else
            Console.WriteLine("   {0} ({1}): <Indexed>", prop.Name,
                              prop.PropertyType.Name);

   }
```

For conversion you can make use of [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Convert.ChangeType(number, typeof(int))
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Based on OP comment:
If you want to check for the type of a property you need the [PropertyType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that you cannot use `as` and `is` on runtime type metadata. If you write

```
var isType = item.Type is MyType;
```

You'll always get `false`, that's because although `item.Type` represents some type, say `MyType` it's type (that is static type) is not `MyType` but a type derived from [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) (usually `RuntimeType`). This really makes sense if you realize that `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` is a runtime construct and `is` is a compile time construct (there is no way the compiler can know what type is represented). So to solve the problem you need to use the runtime facilities to deal with type data.

- Type equally:

  ```
  item.PropertyType == typeof(MyType)
  ```
- [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx):

  ```
  typeof(MyType).IsAssignableFrom(item.PropertyType)
  ```

---

Old answer for reference:

I think you're misunderstanding how reflection works, PropertyInfo only represent the static Metadata about that property you cannot get its value directly, because if you think about it you have some missing information: property from which instance you want to get? `PropertyInfo` isn't bound to any instances. To get the value you need to use [GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var value = item.GetValue(instance);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback. I am not trying to get the value.  The code is in the constructor. I am trying to loop the objects in the  class and if they are of type 'TickData' then I want to add them to a list. I am doing this by attempting the cast using the as keyword. I must be missing something.

Comment: @GKonheiser please add this comment to your question as it completely changes it.